# wso2 identity server with postgres database schema

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Actually I want to setup wso2is 5.3.0 with the postgres schema for production environment, which I have configured as "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2?currentSchema=wso2pgschema" in the masterdatasources.xml file and able to install wso2is in the postgres schema but when I goes to the browser and tries to login its gives me error

**[LOG]**
[2017-05-14 19:15:59,023] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  **Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block**
[2017-05-14 19:15:59,026] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  **System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION**

Is there a way we can install it database schema ?or we have to install it in the database public schema/keep installation with the inbuild  h2 database for production.

Please Help.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a schema other than the `public` schema. Please refer the post [here](https://medium.com/@pulasthi7/configuring-wso2-products-to-use-custom-postgresql-schema-42c44c546a5c) for the steps.

For the second part of the question, the default H2 database is not recommended for production systems.

Comment: Thanks Pulasthi, tried this and its working but in postgres documentation we can connect postgres 9.4 schema as providing the url like "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2?currentSchema=wso2schema" and does not require to execute command "ALTER DATABASE wso2db SET search_path TO public,wso2schema;"